# WebApi Bind from Uri to rich model with IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public string Get([FromUri]TestModel model)
{
    return "";
}
```

This request works as expected: `localhost/get?id=5&clients=1&clients=2`
--> Clients is bound as an array with 2 elements (1 & 2)

But this request acts weird: `localhost/get?id=5&clients=`
--> Clients is bound as an array with 1 element (0)

Both an empty array or null would be acceptable but `int[] {0}`?

Comment: What happens if you don't include the `clients` value on the query string at all?  I suspect that key without a value is invalid.

Comment: Ah you are right, omit the `&clients=` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is technically an invalid URL:

```
localhost/get?id=5&clients=
```

And this is probably confusing the model binder.  It's trying to put *something* in the `clients` property.  And since `clients` is an `int[]` and the default value for `int` is `0`, well, there you go.

To keep the array empty, just omit the value entirely:

```
localhost/get?id=5
```